# Using Tasks instead of Threads wouldn't become bordersome of UI (main thread) in c# 4.5 WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, task-parallel-library, async-await

Alright i am starting to write a very big application.

There will be many multithreaded functions.

As far as i understood all tasks are running under main thread (ui thread).

But i see that many experienced .net developers suggesting use tasks instead of threads.

So i am little confused about whether i should use threads or tasks ?

Having so many tasks would block main thread (ui) at all ?

Example of new task starting

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
 {
      myfunction();
 });
```

Can these types of new tasks block main thread or make it heavy ?

And my second question

The below class and function is created under main thread

```
    public static class PublicStaticFunctions
{
    public static MTObservableCollection<string> ocEventsCollection = new MTObservableCollection<string>();

    private static readonly object _locker_ocEventsCollection = new object();

    public static void AddMsgToEvents(string srMessage)
    {
        lock (_locker_ocEventsCollection)
            ocEventsCollection.Insert(0, srMessage + " - Time: " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString().Split('.')[0]);
    }
}
```

I am using _locker_ocEventsCollection to have lock. Is this thread safe among tasks ? I mean even if they are under different threads would it be still thread safe ?

**1 More question - question 3**

How can i cancel anonymously started task from itself

I mean at above example   myfunction(); is started as a task

Inside   myfunction(); i want to cancel that particular task when certain operation done

How can i achieve that ?

For example

```
private void myfunction ()
{
//some operation

Cancelthistask // how ?

}
```

Comment: `as far as i understood all tasks are running under main thread (ui thread).` your understanding is not correct. Use Tasks :)

Comment: @L.B ty for answer i edited and asked second question can you also check that :D

Comment: Yes it is safe. Any more question?

Comment: @L.B ty added another one :D

Comment: Use `CancellationToken`, although it is not a simple topic.

Comment: @L.B can i give CancellationToken to that new started task and use it inside of itself ? if so how i am looking that :D i mean i should be able to call it inside of that running task

Comment: I think, now, you can use google for more detailed explanations.....

Comment: @L.B using google but couldnt found yet :D

Answer (score 5):

A `Task` is a unit of work (a promise) which will complete sometime in the near future. A task isn't necessarily using a `Thread` behind the scenes to do its work (as we have something called a Promise Task). You can think about it like this: A task is **something you want done**, while a thread is **one possible way to to get that work done**.

Specifically, `Task.Factory.Startnew` or `Task.Run` queue work on the ThreadPool. They provide an abstraction over that ThreadPool for us, and expose a more flexiable API than `Thread`, such as Continuation and Cancellation.

From [`Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool and returns a task
>   handle for that work.

In your example, the code that runs inside the `delegate` will be queued on the ThreadPool, and will not block your UI.

From [`Task Parallelism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Task Parallel Library (TPL) is based on the concept of a task,
>   which represents an asynchronous operation. In some ways, a task
>   resembles a thread or ThreadPool work item, but at a higher level of
>   abstraction. The term task parallelism refers to one or more
>   independent tasks running concurrently. Tasks provide two primary
>   benefits:
>
> - More efficient and more scalable use of system resources.
>     Behind the scenes, tasks are queued to the ThreadPool, which has been
>     enhanced with algorithms that determine and adjust to the number of
>     threads and that provide load balancing to maximize throughput. This
>     makes tasks relatively lightweight, and you can create many of them to
>     enable fine-grained parallelism.
> - More programmatic control than is
>     possible with a thread or work item. Tasks and the framework built
>     around them provide a rich set of APIs that support waiting,
>     cancellation, continuations, robust exception handling, detailed
>     status, custom scheduling, and more.

**Edit:**

For your second question, a `lock` is the means to synchronize access to shared resources across threads. So yes, it would **make it** thread-safe to use a `lock`.

**Edit 2:**

As for your third question, you can use a `CancellationTokenSource` and pass its `CancellationToken` to the created Task:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var cancellationToken = cts.Token;

Task.Run(() =>
 {
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    myfunction();
 }, cancellationToken);

cts.Cancel();
```

If `cts.Cancel` is called before `cancellationToken.ThowIfCancellationRequested`, it will cause that method call to throw a `OperationCanceledException` and the task will return in a cancelled state. Note you have to pass `Task.Run` the CancellationToken. If you dont, it will end up in a faulted state instead of cancelled.

You can read to extent on [*Task Cancellation*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Edit 3:**

I am assuming this is what you wanted:

```
var cancellationToken = cts.Token;

Task.Run(() =>
 {
    cts.Cancel();
     cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    myfunction();
 }, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: ty very much for answer i updated question and added question 3

Comment: Task starts a new function. How can i call cts inside that function ?

Comment: Task is initialized with a `delegate`. You call `cts` outside of `Task.Run`. You pass the `Token` to the delegate.

Comment: ty for answer but i wonder are there any way to call cts inside called function ?

Comment: Yes, as long as you pass the `CancellationToken` to the method, you can call `cts` inside the lambda, it will capture the variable and allow you to call its `Cancel` method. It doesn't really make sense to cancel the method from the "inside". If you still dont understand, ill edit my answer to make it clear

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG http://communitymgt.wikia.com/wiki/Help_Vampire No need to extend your question with endless ones. Your original question  is already answered.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov can you please post an answer for that ty

Comment: Edited my answer. If you have another question, please post it as a new question. Good luck

Comment: Wondering why was this answer down-voted?

Answer (score 2):

> As far as i understood all tasks are running under main thread (ui thread).

No.
Tasks may run on whichever thread they are scheduled on by the `TaskScheduler`. In most cases, including `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `Task.Run` tasks are actually scheduled on a ThreadPool thread and not the UI thread.

As to your second question, a `lock` is always thread-safe. Especially when used by multiple threads.

Comment: ty very much for answer i updated question and added question 3